# Use of in_app_review package in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Could someone please show how in_app_review https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review is used to review flutter apps on google playstore.

A sample code will be very helpful.

Comment: If you look at the link you clicked, you can see usage examples right there.  You could do it on initialization, or in an async callback that checks if they have reviewed before, then execute: `if (await inAppReview.isAvailable()) { inAppReview.requestReview(); }`

Comment: Thank you, I have figured out how to use the package. However, I will like to ask, Please how do I check if the app has been reviewed before by the user

Answer (score 6):

To anyone who is trying to implement this,
Please read through the document which has guidelines on how and where to place the review dialogue.

use the following code in any of your App page:

```
final InAppReview inAppReview = InAppReview.instance;
if (await inAppReview.isAvailable()) {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
   inAppReview.requestReview();
   });
}
```

I would recommend to use it with a delay, so when user views a page, the dialogue for review comes after few seconds.

Also if you are wondering how to check if app was reviewed before or how to make sure this dialogue just doesn't pop up every time,  [please go through this doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test). Dialogue doesn't appear if quota is reached or if user has already reviewed before.

Comment: Can I have a callback for whether a user has reviewed it before or not? 
I need to redirect the user to openStoreListing if already reviewed so he may change his review.

Comment: Why wait 2 secondes before calling the requestReview ?

Comment: Thats a recommendation, You can use without the delay too.
I added delay so when user views a page, the dialogue for review comes after few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package on top of in_app_review which helps handling the conditions on what the app should try to display the rating. If you use https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_in_app_review you can specify

- how many days should elapse before the app should try to display the review dialog
- how many times the app should be opened by the user before the app should try
- how many days should be elapse after a try to try again

All this helps to get reviews from satisfied users as unhappy users may delete the app after the first try. Adding a gap between the install and the try to display may help to overcome this.

Use it like this:

```
AdvancedInAppReview()
  .setMinDaysBeforeRemind(7)
  .setMinDaysAfterInstall(2)
  .setMinLaunchTimes(2)
  .monitor();
```